# python read text from content scraping

Tags: python, search, web, screen-scraping

1, must retrieve a list of all {ID} with the source code and find the largest (code below)

2, after the break must re-download a list of id, find the biggest and compare the ID of the first point

3, If it is larger than the previous one must return a {HASH} largest {ID}

Seriously i need a help :<

Source Code Webpage

```
<tr>
<td style="display:none">id&gt;{ID},id32&gt;{HASH},level,,,,,&gt;{NAME},type",,,
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="display:none">id&gt;{ID},id32&gt;{HASH},level,,,,,&gt;{NAME},type",,,
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="display:none">id&gt;{ID},id32&gt;{HASH},level,,,,,&gt;{NAME},type",,,
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="display:none">id&gt;{ID},id32&gt;{HASH},level,,,,,&gt;{NAME},type",,,
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="display:none">id&gt;{ID},id32&gt;{HASH},level,,,,,&gt;{NAME},type",,,
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Have you written any code or can you give a further explanation? What is this html code, it looks malformed. The `td` doesnt close.

Comment: @PaulRooney type",,,</td> HTML code from source webpage scraping.

Comment: You really do need help.

Comment: now you could use `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` to get tags (and text) from HTML. And then you could use `string` functions or `regular expression` to get `{ID}` from text